# error with update command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
 update EMP 
    set fn = @FN
    set ln = @LN
    set DOB = @DOB
    where id = @ID
```

when i execute the above command. I am getting the follwing error.

```
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

can we update more then one field with single uadate command.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to delimit the fields & you only state `SET` once;

```
 update EMP 
    set fn = @FN,
        ln = @LN,
        DOB = @DOB
 where id = @ID
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to UPDATE multiple columns at the same time. The syntax in this case would look like the following:

```
UPDATE "table_name"
SET column_1 = [value1], column_2 = [value2]
WHERE {condition}
```

Ref: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlupdate.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!